# How to remove character in html with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is the html:

```
  <div class="upme-field-value">
    <div class="upme-rememberme">
        <i class="upme-icon-check-empty"></i>Remember me
        <input type="hidden" name="rememberme" id="rememberme-1" value="0">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="upme-login" class="upme-button upme-login" value="Log In">  
    <br>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="upme-forgot-pass-1" class="upme-login-forgot-link "    
    title="Forget?">Forget?</a> 
    | <-------- **** I want to remove this character****
    <a href="/register/" class="upme-login-register-link 
    ">Register</a> 
  </div>
```

Is There is a way to remove this character "|" from the above html with jQuery or CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work in this problem

```
$('div.upme-field-value').html($('div.upme-field-value').html().replace('|',''))
```

Comment: Simple but effective.

Comment: @AlexDouglas: This is an anti-pattern that shouldn't be used. It's silly to destroy and recreate a section of the DOM just to remove a single text character. You should target the `<a>` element just before the character, then remove the next text node. Much faster and less destructive.

Comment: ...Do it like this: `var a = document.getElementById("upme-forgot-pass-1"); a.parentNode.removeChild(a.nextSibling);`, or use a jQuery equivalent if you prefer slower code.

Comment: @cookiemonster Thanks buddy, I'll use your method instead :)

Answer (score 0):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/X528L/)

Use this:

```
$('div.upme-field-value').html(function(i, html) {
    return html.replace(/\|/g,'');
});
```

Comment: You should definitely not use reg ex in this case.

Comment: Because it is only one, right? I'll update the answer.

Comment: Because it is preferable to do a basic string to string replacement when it is possible.

Comment: If there are more `|` characters it only the first would be removed if you did a simple replace.

Comment: @ValentinMercier and that is based on what criteria?

Comment: @charlietfl A good code is a clean code, so as for me the easier to read it is the better.

Comment: @ValentinMercier that is totally subjective and certainly not a case for `definitely not use`